# iOS App Crashes when running by itself on device, does not crash when running through Xcode using debugger, or in simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode4, ios-simulator

I'm having an issue with my app that runs fine while running when I run using Xcode or the simulator.  Stepping through the debugger isn't any help.  I've looked at the crash logs and I can't figure out what the issue is (frankly I don't know how to read them unless one of my objects is explicitly listed).  There's not much specific to my application, most of the objects listed are lower level items.    Running it via Instruments looking for leaks doesn't turn up anything.  It seems to be clean. I've added NSLogs all over the place to see if I can see any smoking gun, I'm not getting memory warnings, or anything.

The way I can replicate the problem is to schedule a local notification, let it fire then unlock the device and return to the app. When it returns, I post a notification. It does seem to happen more frequently when I unlock immediately after the notification appears, before it disappears again.  I've been beating my head agains this for a few days and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the most recent crash log, if the crash log helps you figure out what the issue is, can you please tell me how you know?:

```
    Incident Identifier: 61F49DCD-F1AA-4329-B9E7-88D5CE03548D
    CrashReporter Key:   59c846cb8589d246d69bd796ee338c7dfb12158a
    Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
    Process:         myApp [179]
    Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/73AF6B85-2002-4230-90CC-B4AC3F075984/myApp.app/myApp
    Identifier:      myApp
    Version:         ??? (???)
    Code Type:       ARM (Native)
    Parent Process:  launchd [1]

    Date/Time:       2011-06-04 23:48:11.849 -0400
    OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.3 (8J2)
    Report Version:  104

    Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
    Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x7001eae8
    Crashed Thread:  0

    Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34499c96 objc_msgSend + 14
    1   myApp                       0x0001d014 0x1000 + 114708
    2   myApp                       0x0001cee4 0x1000 + 114404
    3   Foundation                      0x341c117c _nsnote_callback + 136
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x3094f208 __CFXNotificationPost_old + 396
    5   CoreFoundation                  0x308e9ee4 _CFXNotificationPostNotification + 112
    6   Foundation                      0x341be5cc -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 64
    7   Foundation                      0x341c01ba -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:] + 18
    8   myApp                       0x00002e50 0x1000 + 7760
    9   myApp                       0x00002f0a 0x1000 + 7946
    10  UIKit                           0x30b392fa -[UIApplication _callApplicationResumeHandlersForURL:payload:] + 246
    11  UIKit                           0x30b3c684 -[UIApplication _handleApplicationResumeEvent:] + 744
    12  UIKit                           0x309e6e20 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 2724
    13  UIKit                           0x309e620e -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 38
    14  UIKit                           0x309e5c4c _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5084
    15  GraphicsServices                0x30269e70 PurpleEventCallback + 660
    16  CoreFoundation                  0x30957a90 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
    17  CoreFoundation                  0x30959838 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 160
    18  CoreFoundation                  0x3095a606 __CFRunLoopRun + 514
    19  CoreFoundation                  0x308eaebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
    20  CoreFoundation                  0x308eadc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
    21  GraphicsServices                0x30269418 GSEventRunModal + 108
    22  GraphicsServices                0x302694c4 GSEventRun + 56
    23  UIKit                           0x30a10d62 -[UIApplication _run] + 398
    24  UIKit                           0x30a0e800 UIApplicationMain + 664
    25  myApp                       0x000021ea 0x1000 + 4586
    26  myApp                       0x00002188 0x1000 + 4488

    Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
    Thread 1:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35590fbc kevent + 24
    1   libdispatch.dylib               0x35261032 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 706
    2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3526203a _dispatch_queue_invoke + 86
    3   libdispatch.dylib               0x352615ea _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 186
    4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3566758a _pthread_wqthread + 258
    5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35667bbc start_wqthread + 0

    Thread 2 name:  WebThread
    Thread 2:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558dc5c semaphore_wait_signal_trap + 8
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558df52 semaphore_wait_signal + 2
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35664734 pthread_mutex_lock + 256
    3   WebCore                         0x35f533ee _WebTryThreadLock(bool) + 150
    4   WebCore                         0x35f5332e WebRunLoopLock(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 14
    5   CoreFoundation                  0x30957a2e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 10
    6   CoreFoundation                  0x3095945e __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 406
    7   CoreFoundation                  0x3095a760 __CFRunLoopRun + 860
    8   CoreFoundation                  0x308eaebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
    9   CoreFoundation                  0x308eadc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
    10  WebCore                         0x35f5327e RunWebThread(void*) + 382
    11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3566630a _pthread_start + 242
    12  libsystem_c.dylib               0x35667bb4 thread_start + 0

    Thread 3:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558dc00 mach_msg_trap + 20
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558d758 mach_msg + 44
    2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558a630 thread_policy + 116
    3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35665b3e pthread_setschedparam_internal + 62
    4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x356673c6 pthread_setschedparam + 74
    5   TextInput                       0x318a15aa KB::kb_set_thread_priority(int) + 18
    6   TextInput                       0x318921b4 KB::BackgroundLoad(void*) + 84
    7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3566630a _pthread_start + 242
    8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35667bb4 thread_start + 0

    Thread 4:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x355903ec __workq_kernreturn + 8
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x356676d8 _pthread_wqthread + 592
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35667bbc start_wqthread + 0

    Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
        r0: 0x7001eae8    r1: 0x312c7008      r2: 0x000269d8      r3: 0x0002bb94
        r4: 0x00000001    r5: 0x00000001      r6: 0x00000002      r7: 0x2fdfe160
        r8: 0x00000000    r9: 0x001fc0a0     r10: 0x00000001     r11: 0x00000001
        ip: 0x3f3212f8    sp: 0x2fdfe124      lr: 0x0001d01b      pc: 0x34a92c96
      cpsr: 0x20000030

    Binary Images:
        0x1000 -    0x26fff +myApp armv7  <4a1f799472b13315b16261c09555ec39> /var/mobile/Applications/73AF6B85-2002-4230-90CC-B4AC3F075984/myApp.app/myApp
       0xd6000 -    0xdafff  AccessibilitySettingsLoader armv7  <977d3eb9b0a4389e85e0e8eb64806759> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/AccessibilitySettingsLoader.bundle/AccessibilitySettingsLoader
      0x4ca000 -   0x504fff  UIKit armv7  <5a81f85811d035d988a9dbd89a79fb7b> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/UIKit.axbundle/UIKit
    0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe25fff  dyld armv7  <bb9bfc7d242331d29a79adf7ef7aaa18> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x305fe000 - 0x30627fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <57fef84bdc17301d8bf53ba0fb967fe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
    0x30628000 - 0x3065ffff  Security armv7  <6599f42a910b3b31a0e1d98c883d61cb> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
    0x30660000 - 0x30661fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <39bf0f48bd8539169a77f8f61cdcd4c9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
    0x306be000 - 0x306befff  Accelerate armv7  <7d5ad465049136afaa1f0d89aac600bc> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
    0x307bc000 - 0x30851fff  ImageIO armv7  <d520e3241d1130e8ac1375ee0f2c1095> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
    0x3085e000 - 0x3086afff  GraphicsServices armv7  <ff78a9636e933f0dbd222f8d26209788> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
    0x3097f000 - 0x309b3fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <570c63dc3a273a5a8c9072fd5567f5c1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
    0x309c9000 - 0x309cbfff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <a2631ac302f4310dae8367939e16b7c2> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
    0x309cc000 - 0x30ae6fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <bada0c2725bb31a483d5adf9aaf1f8df> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x30aeb000 - 0x30b01fff  EAP8021X armv7  <9fefc0ada30435fbb3b51818c74f6cb8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
    0x30c8f000 - 0x30c96fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <55f29184efcc3046bb833dd72a4487e1> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
    0x30c9a000 - 0x30ca2fff  MobileBluetooth armv7  <63f11756c4aa3262b2317ff3b8e2a977> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
    0x30ca3000 - 0x30ca3fff  vecLib armv7  <0c60cd0a60f43d2791d36cb357d30e3c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
    0x30cd0000 - 0x30cdffff  UIAccessibility armv7  <414b92afa9713ae092e8b6dd300d4c73> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIAccessibility.framework/UIAccessibility
    0x30ce0000 - 0x30d1dfff  CoreText armv7  <fb6a72faec2330c4b2cd33c2e9c59588> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
    0x30e28000 - 0x30e76fff  CoreMotion armv7  <58c353bb7e33361f881da07c72f4cdfb> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
    0x30e77000 - 0x30ed6fff  CorePDF armv7  <f198f0d47ade34699ed5cb93226f46bb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CorePDF.framework/CorePDF
    0x30edb000 - 0x30fc0fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <a8444f997111304c9571b3ff974b769c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
    0x30fdb000 - 0x31368fff  UIKit armv7  <c271b78464d93cb7bf28c6e49df293ba> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
    0x31389000 - 0x31476fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <f4146ce07e3031ea8a81fa5516fd77d0> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
    0x31477000 - 0x31478fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <e8858a499d663e6a9e3c188521273cc1> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x31479000 - 0x31483fff  AccountSettings armv7  <d083fb384dc7311eb6766b9b2d2dd9c8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
    0x31489000 - 0x31492fff  CoreVideo armv7  <ea847e6dba2d36b1826b255c73b39539> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
    0x314e3000 - 0x314e5fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <d55f1553d14831a2a5435ae27ef75ef4> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
    0x314e6000 - 0x31537fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <8a41cc6a6d9332308bc415d27577fd24> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
    0x31551000 - 0x31558fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <0a082e1d475432959ba93aa3dbf7fb31> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
    0x31559000 - 0x3159cfff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <f790c26852cb3cf298abe56bc9a3940b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
    0x3159d000 - 0x315a2fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <f5ccc8234aea3ebd9a88bd37f0fa23ae> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
    0x315dd000 - 0x315e8fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <ac706bee36593dc683fd5a96a389d72e> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x315e9000 - 0x31735fff  MediaToolbox armv7  <482b13059e8a329fa5d832baede25103> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
    0x31759000 - 0x31759fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <21415179ffa03f949fa8cc851c6c31c7> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
    0x3175a000 - 0x3175bfff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <ccc041df3de73eafb7a59e74cdb1702b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
    0x3175c000 - 0x3177cfff  PrintKit armv7  <e5a01ca9083a36afacc08611a398e2ad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
    0x31789000 - 0x317cbfff  CoreAudio armv7  <c972fd5f8e89333ca680b9a33587f896> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
    0x31d56000 - 0x31d96fff  CoreMedia armv7  <8e0570582ba535bfa74f1f00eef64376> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
    0x31d9e000 - 0x31dd6fff  IOKit armv7  <80ae313ad69d3363935c88e51a11862d> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
    0x31e17000 - 0x31e53fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <9d97699e44ee3651ba4ac37e5adec35b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
    0x31e7e000 - 0x338ccfff  TextInput armv7  <f242acc046073c1598195dd26fd8ad6f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
    0x33a19000 - 0x33a1efff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <8c35c090bc373cb181fc26b961b8dba5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
    0x33a1f000 - 0x33a28fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <03d98d5cf6383695aa7d8a88da52f410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
    0x33b32000 - 0x33b35fff  ApplePushService armv7  <015c68c15621348db9f6a012499170e1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
    0x33b36000 - 0x33b7cfff  CoreTelephony armv7  <af7d1e770e5a3ffd8834a57fb5d40557> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
    0x33b7d000 - 0x33b89fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <c68262667ac8397a949ce4e92dfec7db> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
    0x33c5e000 - 0x33c60fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <683f321680763e519d61541170ba2133> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
    0x33c61000 - 0x33c66fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <e57c2b9054b831d9a37119baaa4947cb> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
    0x33d52000 - 0x33d56fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <a0772a32cd8b3b9194bb0c29807c1c5b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
    0x33db2000 - 0x33dc4fff  VoiceServices armv7  <d219dd8a59c93390b3461a015e28b29c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VoiceServices.framework/VoiceServices
    0x33e8c000 - 0x33e90fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <e1cbfe599c96369ca4bdb0dd99d3cd9f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
    0x33e92000 - 0x33f43fff  WebKit armv7  <eb9a0d69c64b3127b2bffd71641add3b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
    0x33f44000 - 0x33f51fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <0a1e2bb78d5138419ecad8ba0fe42fdd> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
    0x3402a000 - 0x34030fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <14c89b7346433c1f8675f454531f6ca3> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
    0x34031000 - 0x34139fff  CoreData armv7  <9843a401dd1d322383e3e40021cc8b95> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
    0x3430b000 - 0x3430cfff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <41a7b5e5d9983449ab33affed0f635ad> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
    0x34376000 - 0x34378fff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <9e7efa009730322f84bbc5d8bf1ded94> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
    0x34379000 - 0x3437cfff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <43311c113a9d3182b7d007129819f029> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
    0x3437d000 - 0x34392fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <e92cfbb83f7b330db19181e797bb3f7b> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
    0x34599000 - 0x3459cfff  IOSurface armv7  <ad50e71624583d06b891344d832f9b08> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
    0x3459d000 - 0x345ebfff  GMM armv7  <049361f664eb3f30b0d25cd56ffc1f0f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
    0x3469d000 - 0x346fcfff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <0b36b2272aa33a8c9aa22d99c89d7189> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
    0x346fd000 - 0x34781fff  AVFoundation armv7  <eeaf5f4f822436a5bd1655f536e69879> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
    0x347ac000 - 0x348cbfff  Foundation armv7  <09ff368178c5321c9715b9c8d491d53f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
    0x34998000 - 0x34a47fff  QuartzCore armv7  <ef9632c9781f3101916b65e9faae1579> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
    0x34a48000 - 0x34a8efff  CoreLocation armv7  <c1924042951e3df98515c7bf36093c1c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
    0x34a90000 - 0x34b54fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <6b51e76fde9f381bb7b3bc5badbfee3a> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x34d3a000 - 0x34d6dfff  AppSupport armv7  <0217468bd9f839229a47910b7816b3d5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
    0x34d6e000 - 0x34d75fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <ab9777b39e8e3026ad64dc90323cad7e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
    0x34d76000 - 0x34d77fff  DataMigration armv7  <42e9e87a4e0735c3837e27d4f2adcf55> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
    0x34d78000 - 0x34e99fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <65f6c8701b563542820a26b0dfc4f6a4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
    0x34ec7000 - 0x34ed3fff  AXRuntime armv7  <6698f47f8d1732579ebd62fff9c35035> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AXRuntime.framework/AXRuntime
    0x34eda000 - 0x351c7fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <b855d60dac01310495453bddfd004f0d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
    0x351f3000 - 0x35228fff  AddressBook armv7  <3f2071a77bc134cd82065eef90d4082f> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
    0x35229000 - 0x352e8fff  CFNetwork armv7  <b09e0d53de9f3bc8bde494780f3cdd4f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
    0x352e9000 - 0x35302fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <4825c3e392983aba947eca06555e4480> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
    0x35423000 - 0x35577fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <6619c8c13f8d328e923e797fa8d0df23> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
    0x35618000 - 0x35619fff  CoreSurface armv7  <7b83cd757da73e6e826693c29296d3fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
    0x3561e000 - 0x356c7fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <5538d3f2c7d83b88b06168488fe6326b> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
    0x356f2000 - 0x356f7fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <c7cfe523e2d73521abc01587313ef730> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
    0x357e5000 - 0x35802fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <48016be86e3f3cd9aeee1c6590e1ac6f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
    0x35803000 - 0x3580dfff  ExternalAccessory armv7  <eebb4bdbbefb37419b884ffa011e1dc5> /System/Library/Frameworks/ExternalAccessory.framework/ExternalAccessory
    0x3583c000 - 0x3584efff  PersistentConnection armv7  <659ea9d5b13d3fefb37acff09016a69c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
    0x3584f000 - 0x35853fff  libcache.dylib armv7  <d2f7fd2a352b3cd59c564be34b53cf80> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
    0x35854000 - 0x35861fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9a0511ad5ebc3db898f1f49ed1a73d34> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
    0x35892000 - 0x358d1fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <33dcf9a403ae3fd5971d6030ada2fcab> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x358d2000 - 0x358d2fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <42d8aa2a31843a6e8bfff745644a7ba5> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
    0x35971000 - 0x359e0fff  ProofReader armv7  <6d843c6aecdd37ae84baa40af8ad7e65> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
    0x359e1000 - 0x35a36fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <0221caba81a235c5a896a835e2aac047> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
    0x35a3d000 - 0x35a43fff  IAP armv7  <c0f4c99a1b493e489948f231ad9238e2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
    0x35a44000 - 0x35b70fff  libmecabra.dylib armv7  <113de5f9858c32b8b158bfdc68042a97> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
    0x35b73000 - 0x35b76fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <fc834fd33a18341ea7506587ad895703> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
    0x35b77000 - 0x35b8efff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <a06ec84e53bf32098b63c0caebdb45b6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x35bdd000 - 0x35c27fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <b2cac408951c3f3c9ba3cf563e54ce81> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
    0x35c28000 - 0x35c2afff  MobileInstallation armv7  <94b6d6c5d9883175af26764567528127> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
    0x35c2c000 - 0x35cadfff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <a7077267b6743ed3bbdd86d4380c75d9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    0x35cae000 - 0x35ce6fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <ccea634795153164a681f0f311f4461d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
    0x35ce9000 - 0x35d8ffff  Celestial armv7  <7fbd02fa664b33babaf0327c320d1491> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
    0x36112000 - 0x36216fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <61a94142e2d23dafa2964190dd46e9e3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
    0x36217000 - 0x3622afff  libmis.dylib armv7  <529ea6e3a87230ce9f6cf3285c22429c> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
    0x36274000 - 0x36293fff  Bom armv7  <b178e3efb4d733c694bd5a55e57a314f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
    0x36546000 - 0x36b51fff  WebCore armv7  <07941e59d0a33f94802c16c76238fddf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
    0x36b52000 - 0x36b58fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <f9277ee9b85b3722975ad319a323aca0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
    0x36c26000 - 0x36c55fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <1d73b8a159363f96bb9c039655c5eae6> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
    0x36c5f000 - 0x36c6dfff  OpenGLES armv7  <5a76beaeaa013f0cbf16e5cb154598ab> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
    0x36c80000 - 0x36c85fff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9d7198e91de9386a9e5ea43608a66a57> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
    0x36d88000 - 0x36d88fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <f47c01d627853b328e088b3fdd08e87d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
```

Comment: Could you also post the error text from within the console when you're running it on device?

Comment: That was part of the problem, I was getting no error in the console.  If I ran it in Xcode, there was no error, if I ran it just on the device, I would get nothing other than my own NSLog messages.

Comment: Oh right, I assumed that running on device within Xcode produced the above error too. I've not really worked with notifications, and usually been lucky enough to get console errors in situations like this... can you post any of your code that deals with posting notifications?

Comment: It was a memory management issue essentially, but it was difficult for me to track down.  Seemed to fall into a little bit of a blindspot where the normally debugging tools couldn't show me what was going on.  Or I just didn't know how to interpret the info they were giving me.

Comment: Can you briefly describe the error and how you solved it, for when other people stumble across your question?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether your developer certificate has expired?

I've just come across similar problem and noticed that my certificate was expired yesterday! Re-requested the certificate and the app started again on my iPad. Sadly XCode doesn't present any error messages about it.

Comment: Oh just noticed you said the iOS app crashed, not XCode. So the answer might not be relevant to your problem...

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but the same thing happened to me when working with Xcode 11. I was able to fix it by including CoreGraphics.framework and other frameworks I was using in the list of "Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content" for my app. I do not know why it would even run with the debugger connected...